# Sprint JPA - Sorting by other table's column

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

Please check the following case:

```
class ParentClass {

    List<ChildClass> children;

}

class ChildClass {}

class SortingClass {}
```

Basically, *ParentClass* has a **@OneToMany** relation with *ChildClass*, while *ChildClass* could be joined (**@ManyToMany**) with *SortingClass* in order to sort *ChildClass* objects inside the *ParentClass* once returned to the caller.

In the very end, *ParentClass* should have *ChildClass* items sorted by a specific *SortingClass* attribute, which **shall not** be included in the ResultSet given back to the caller.

i.e. *ChildClass* is a DATE item (start, end, process, etc.), while *SortingClass* states that the START DATE item shall come before the END DATE one when positioning those two items in the final front-end view.

How could I achieve this with Spring/Repository JPA annotations?
Shall I move this sorting to the front-end application, having both information (parent/child and sorting) as separated?

Thank you.

Regards,
A.M.

Comment: You are focusing on the view of the data you want returned for one specific use case. To help though, we need to know what the entity/model looks like that you would use for all crud operations. How do you expect such a model to be written/persisted to the database? I don't see that the parent's list of children should be affected by what appears to be business logic in a ManyToMany collection in each child. If you need children sorted this way, query for ChildClass directly, which will allow you to put in complex filters and sorting into the query

Answer (score 0):

You can use @OrderBy to achieve this:

```
class ParentClass {

    @OrderBy("fieldName ASC")
    List<ChildClass> children;

}
```

Comment: Hello. I tried that, but it doesn't work. See, the fieldname there belongs to SortingClass, which is not part of the selection, hence if I put that annotation there, I get an Exception stating that "fieldname" is not a field of ChildClass, nor of ParentClass.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the classes are composed in this way:

```java
class ParentClass {
    private long id;
    private List<ChildClass> children;

}

class ChildClass {
    private SortingClass fieldName
}

class SortingClass {
    private LocalDate start;
}
```

A Spring Data Repository can be created with these methods:

```java
@Repository
class ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<ParentClass, Long> {

    Optional<ParentClass> findByIdOrderByChildrenFieldNameStartAsc(long id);
    
    List<ParentClass> findAllOrderByChildrenFieldNameStartAsc();

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I get the following error: *Error Msg = ORA-00942: table or view does not exist*

Comment: could you provide the list of tables and columns?

Comment: Did my answer help you? or do you want me to add something to my answer? otherwise, feel free to accept my answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to perform the following:

```
class ParentClass {
    
    private List<ChildClass> children;

}

class ChildClass {

    @Id
    private String anotherId;

    @Id
    private String sortKey;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas(value = {
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "GROUP", referencedColumnName = "sortingGroup")),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "sortKey", referencedColumnName = "sortingKey", insertable = false, updatable = false))
    })
    private SortingClass sort;

}

class SortingClass {
    
    @Id
    private String sortingGroup;

    @Id
    private String sortingKey;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sort", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ChildClass> children;

}
```

In order to sort by the *SortingClass* **sortingKey** attribute, I would first need to join those two tables. The problem is that *SortingClass* has a composite key, and one of its attributes shall be constant.

Using *@JoinColumnsOrFormulas* gives me the following error, though:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.Formula cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.Column

I am struggling on the correct way to join those two entities, just to sort *ChildClass* by a *SortingClass* single attribute...

Answer (score 0):

The following is a brief scheme of the real DB I am currently working on.

- ORDER

Each ORDER item is identified by an ID, which is unique.

- ORDER_DATE

Each ORDER_DATE is connected to a specific ORDER ID, and the same ORDER could have more than 1 ORDER_DATE item (i.e. Start Date, End Date, etc.).

- KEYS

Common table which contains several key-value pairs. In this case, each ORDER_DATE has a TYPE key which is the main JOIN with KEYS. KEYS gives the order in which the dates shall appear (i.e. Start Date should come before End Date). KEYS items are identified by a composite key (GROUP,TYPE), but for dates the GROUP is fixed (i.e. "DATE").